# opencart menu bar doesn't show items/links

Tags: opencart

i recently moved an opencart shop from a subfolder to the root direcoty and now the menu bar items (aka links) don't show up. They're completely gone. I have correctly configured both config.php files when moving the shop, I have also uninstalled the theme and still the items are missing. Also, there's some kind of an error on the homepage. Otherwise, it works fine

Here is the link:
ecig-juice.ca

Also, when I click on a link from down below, say "Desserts" I get the following errors:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/ecigadmin/public_html/catalog/view/theme/rgen-opencart/template/common/header.tpl on line 8

Fatal error: Call to a member function cssGroup() on a non-object in /home/ecigadmin/public_html/catalog/view/theme/rgen-opencart/template/common/header.tpl on line 43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make necessary updates in your .htaccess file.

Change the line :

`RewriteBase /subfoldername/`

to

`RewriteBase /`